# Spartacus navigate to page

Tags: cart, response.redirect, spartacus-storefront, navigateurl

I created an Order History custom page with a button to "Reorder" a cart.
After reorder the cart I want to navigate to the cart page but I'm redirected back to my page with a "No Authorization" message.
[image]
This is what I use to navigate

```
location.reload(); // refresh cart

this.routingService.go('cart');
```

If I go to the page through the cart icon everything works ok. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cart not found

happens if no cart exists in Backoffice.

you should refresh the cart with `this.multiCartService.reloadCart(cartId)` instead of reloading the page.

Answer (score -1):

`location.reload();` reloads the current URL. You can try to remove it, and just go to cart page by `this.routingService.go('cart');`.